# Compare data in two columns and print difference in 3rd column

Tags: excel

In excel I am looking to do the following:

If a value in "Column B" exists anywhere in "Column A", print said value to "Column C"

and

If a value exists in "Column B" and does not exist in "Column A", print said value to "Column D"

So..

In a sheet where,

"Column A" has: `1, 2, 3, 4`

"Column B" has: `1, 3, 5`

I want,

"Column C" to populate "`1`" and "`3`"

"Column D" to populate "`5`"

```
- A     B     C     D
- 1     1     1     5
- 2     3     3
- 3     5
- 4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use `IF()` formula and fill down:

```
 | A | B |                    C                                |                          D                          |
1| 1 | 1 |=IF(COUNTIF($A$1:$A$4,B1)>0,IF(ISBLANK(B1),"",B1),"")|=IF(COUNTIF($A$1:$A$4,B1)=0,IF(ISBLANK(B1),"",B1),"")|
2| 2 | 3 |
3| 3 | 5 |
4| 4 |   |
```

Then result will be like this:

```
 | A | B | C | D |
1| 1 | 1 | 1 |   |
2| 2 | 3 | 3 |   |
3| 3 | 5 |   | 5 |
4| 4 |   |   |   |
```

Comment: This worked almost exactly as intended! 
http://imgur.com/a/jL3vd
Is there a way to prevent the "0" in the other cells?

Answer (score 0):

If you want them to appear without spaces, try

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$1:$B$3,SMALL(IF(COUNTIF($A$1:$A$5,$B$1:$B$3),ROW($B$1:$B$3)),ROW())),"")
```

and

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$1:$B$3,SMALL(IF(COUNTIF($A$1:$A$5,$B$1:$B$3)=0,ROW($B$1:$B$3)),ROW())),"")
```

Both of these are array formulae and must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>